# PHPMailer не работает

Tags: php

Нужно сделать так чтобы адрес отправки менялся в зависимости от переменной в форме,c $info все работает,а вот с $imya нет. Выдается error и все.И если прописать 1 емейл то все работает

```
    <?php 

require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';


$info = $_POST['info'];
$imya = $_POST['imya'];

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.mail.ru';                                                                                             // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'mail@mail.ru'; // Ваш логин от почты с которой будут отправляться письма
$mail->Password = 'Password'; // Ваш пароль от почты с которой будут отправляться письма
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465; // TCP port to connect to / этот порт может отличаться у других провайдеров

$mail->setFrom('mail@mail.ru'); // от кого будет уходить письмо?
$mail->addAddress('$imya');     // Кому будет уходить письмо 
//$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
//$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
//$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');
//$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Компания';
$mail->Body    = '' .$info;
$mail->AltBody = '';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Error';
} else {
    header('location: thank-you.html');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$mail->addAddress($imya);` Нужно было убрать кавычки

Answer (score 0):

Уберите кавычки `$mail->addAddress('$imya');`